# Android resource linking failed that error appeared to me

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I got this error when I am trying to run my app, so how to fix it ?

C:\Users\oem.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b29f469d834fe6ac53c0c0e264e4ef98\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.

Comment: share your res/values files issue is here

Comment: I have update the post kindly check again

Answer (score 0):

For those who have this issue in android change the version dependencies
ex implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:x.x.x'